# Custom Field in WooCommerce variations

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to find the solution of get the custom field variation data in a front end. I am not sure how to get the variation id on changing the list box of variation product. For example variable product as color contain red, blue, green. I added the custom field for all the color combination.

Here is the code that I tried ([source](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/))

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variable_fields', 10, 2);
//JS to add fields for new variations
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes_js', 'variable_fields_js');
//Save variation fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'save_variable_fields', 10, 1);

/**
 * Create new fields for variations
 *
 */
function variable_fields($loop, $variation_data) {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
// Select
            woocommerce_wp_select(
                    array(
                        'id' => '_select[' . $loop . ']',
                        'label' => __('My Select Field', 'woocommerce'),
                        'description' => __('Choose a value.', 'woocommerce'),
                        'value' => $variation_data['_select'][0],
                        'options' => array(
                            'one' => __('Option 1', 'woocommerce'),
                            'two' => __('Option 2', 'woocommerce'),
                            'three' => __('Option 3', 'woocommerce')
                        )
                    )
            );
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}

/**
 * Create new fields for new variations
 *
 */
function variable_fields_js() {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
// Select
            woocommerce_wp_select(
                    array(
                        'id' => '_select[ + loop + ]',
                        'label' => __('My Select Field', 'woocommerce'),
                        'description' => __('Choose a value.', 'woocommerce'),
                        'value' => $variation_data['_select'][0],
                        'options' => array(
                            'one' => __('Option 1', 'woocommerce'),
                            'two' => __('Option 2', 'woocommerce'),
                            'three' => __('Option 3', 'woocommerce')
                        )
                    )
            );
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}

/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
 */
function save_variable_fields($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['variable_sku'])) :

        $variable_sku = $_POST['variable_sku'];
        $variable_post_id = $_POST['variable_post_id'];
// Text Field
        $_select = $_POST['_select'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($variable_sku); $i++) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if (isset($_select[$i])) {
                update_post_meta($variation_id, '_select', stripslashes($_select[$i]));
            }
        endfor;
// Checkbox

    endif;
}
```

It all saving correctly but in the front end i can't get the value of the corresponding variation but i am still finding a solution. 
Like in a front end if you change the variation it changing the price simultaneously. I am want to display another information on top of the variation price. Is that possible to do in woocommerce. 
Here is the screenshot.

**Backend Variable Product**
[image: backend variable product]

**Expected Output in Front End**
[image]

How to show the custom field data on changing the list box?

Answer (score 2):

brasofilo,

I wrote a tutorial/example on this issue here:

http://blueskysessions.com/2014/03/31/woocommerce-display-dynamic-content-per-the-selected-product-variation/

I had the same question and figured out a way to do it.
This is not as simple as one might think. It requires a little bit of everything but ultimately the trick lies in using jQuery to show and hide content.