# Add custom dimension fields to each variation settings for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I'm trying to add a "Built Dimensions" fields to each product variation settings.

Here's a mock of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: Here's a mock of what I'm trying to accomplish.]

I've followed these following tips but they aren't doing quite what I want:

- http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/
- [Add Advanced Custom Fields to WooCommerce Product Variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264813/add-advanced-custom-fields-to-woocommerce-product-variation)

Those are adding it to one of the other data tabs. I need it per variation. Each variation has a built dimension and a shipping dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated** for better compatibility with WooCommerce custom tables.*

With the 2 hooked functions below, you will get exactly what you are expecting like in your mock:

```php
// Add variation custom "dimentions" fields
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_dimensions', 'add_variation_options_built_dimensions', 10, 3);
function add_variation_options_built_dimensions($loop, $variation_data, $variation)
{
    $variation_built_lenght = get_post_meta($variation->ID, "_built_lenght", true);
    if (!$variation_built_lenght) $variation_built_lenght = "";

    $variation_built_width = get_post_meta($variation->ID, "_built_width", true);
    if (!$variation_built_width) $variation_built_width = "";

    $variation_built_height = get_post_meta($variation->ID, "_built_height", true);
    if (!$variation_built_height) $variation_built_height = "";
    ?>
    <p class="form-field form-row dimensions_field built_dimensions hide_if_variation_virtual form-row-last">

        <label for="product_built_length"><?php
    // translators: %s: dimension unit
    printf(
        __('Built dimensions (L&times;W&times;H) (%s)', 'woocommerce'),
        get_option('woocommerce_dimension_unit')
    );
    ?></label>

    <?php echo wc_help_tip(__('Built length x width x height in decimal form', 'woocommerce')); ?>
    <span class="wrap">
        <input id="product_built_length" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Built length', 'woocommerce'); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="built_lenght_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_built_lenght); ?>" />
        <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Built width', 'woocommerce'); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="built_width_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_built_width); ?>" />
        <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Built height', 'woocommerce'); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal last" size="6" type="text" name="built_height_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($variation_built_height); ?>" />
    </span>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Save the custom dimension fields values:

```php
//Save variation custom "dimensions" fields
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_variation_options_built_dimensions', 10, 2);
function save_variation_options_built_dimensions($variation, $loop)
{
    $built_lenght = $_POST["built_lenght_{$loop}"];
    if (!empty($built_lenght)) {
        $variation->update_meta_data('_built_lenght', sanitize_text_field($built_lenght));
    }
        
    $built_width = $_POST["built_width_{$loop}"];
    if (!empty($built_width)) {
        $variation->update_meta_data('_built_width', sanitize_text_field($built_width));
    }
        
    $built_height = $_POST["built_height_{$loop}"];
    if (!empty($built_height)) {
        $variation->update_meta_data('_built_height', sanitize_text_field($built_height));
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce version 3.8 and above.

You will get this:

[image]