# Display in additional information tab, some product settings custom fields values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

I have added some custom fields to the WooCommerce product setting pages in the shipping tab.

I need to make it visible on Product page in Additional Information tab and also that it can be automatically used in compare plugins?

I need that it add the units also as in the existing weight and dimensions field.

Thanks.

Comment: One of the units is as Dimensions created from from three different parameters.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - I used your code, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212221/add-custom-fields-to-woocomerce-product-setting-pages-in-the-shipping-tab?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I will see it on product page in additional information tab like dimensions and weight see picture [link](http://www.grand-tech.eu/2/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/xxx.jpeg) and also that it will be automatically used in compare functions. You can check it on the build site [link](http://www.grand-tech.eu/2/). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update 2**

Based on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45213169/3730754) made to one of your questions, here is the way to get this custom product fields data on front-end single product pages "Additional information" tab.

**You will get that:**

[image]

**For this product settings custom fields:**

[image]

As the custom fields are saved in the product meta data, we use Wordpress [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function to get the values this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab', 20, 1 );
function custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab( $product ) {

    //Product ID - WooCommerce compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // Get your custom fields data
    $custom_field1 = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_meta_field1', true );
    $custom_field2 = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_meta_field2', true );

    // Set your custom fields labels (or names)
    $label1 = __( 'Your label 1', 'woocommerce');
    $label2 = __( 'Your label 2', 'woocommerce');

    // The Output
    echo '<h3>'. __('Some title', 'woocommerce') .'</h3>
    <table class="custom-fields-data">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="custom-field1">
                <th>'. $label1 .'</th>
                <td>'. $custom_field1 .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="custom-field2">
                <th>'. $label2 .'</th>
                <td>'. $custom_field2 .'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works

> Now to use that data in your compare feature **is an other question** and you should provide, **in a new question**, the code involved in this compare feature…

---

Related answers:

[Add custom dimension fields to each variation settings for variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172481/add-custom-dimension-fields-to-each-variation-settings-for-variable-products/45176566#45176566)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I put the code in the function.php but it will not show the table. I have added the product some data to the fields that is there something to show, but I can't see it. And I have a question to this code. The added fields will be added to the existing table or as a new table? Maybe there is a problem. You can look [HERE](http://www.grand-tech.eu/2/product/small-case-dc-171305x/) how its look like. The Additional informations tab was renamed by me to the Product Data.

Comment: And for what is this part: ` $custom_field1 = 'first-value';
    $custom_field2 = 'second-value'; ` while it fulfil the variable with fixed information and overwrite the correct data?

Comment: It will still not show the table or parameters in front end on product page in additional informations tab the added custom fields. You can see it on the link that I post above. And to the dimensions field isn't needed to change also the definition of the field array that it can accept three parameters and not only one (3x placeholder)?

Comment: Sorry, but it will not show the table ... I don't know why. I have copied your code and paste to the function.php. I fount that on the end of echo line isn't ";" but it doesn't helped. Isn't there a problem that all is PHP function? And isn't possible and easier to add it to the existing table? While it will better for me. The dimensions code I have put there and make on it some changes and its now shown in the back-end. See [HERE](http://www.grand-tech.eu/2/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/backend.jpeg)

Comment: I need change the comment above, the dimension code is working only visually, but it doesn't store the data. I put there only numbers like "7.5".

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing, but I wanted to add the custom fields to the existing table, without creating a new one.

Sod if you want to add it into the additionnal information table you can use woocommerce_display_product_attributes filter

```php
function yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes($product_attributes, $product){
    $product_attributes['customfield'] = [
        'label' => __('custom', 'text-domain'),
        'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'customfield', true),
    ];
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2);
```