# Display all the variants with custom data in WooCommerce additional informations tab in a single table row

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I have one product with multiple variants, and I'd like to display all the variants (not attributes) with their relative SKU in the additional informations tab, like so:

[image]

Based on [Display in additional information tab, some product settings custom fields values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298264/11987538) I added the code to the informations tab of my product:

Where `$custom_field1` should be the result of the attribute's name + the SKU and the GTIN (added by this plugin):

- [Product GTIN (EAN, UPC, ISBN) for WooCommerce](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/product-gtin-ean-upc-isbn-for-woocommerce/)

**Notes:**

1. Simple products should remain unaffected
2. The result should be just an extra row of the already existing table, or possibly replace the "attributes" rows.
3. The GTIN code is a private custom field of product with meta_key _wpm_gtin_code, If you have the product object you can get the GTIN code in this way: `$gtin = $product->get_meta('_wpm_gtin_code');`

Comment: Some questions: **1)** it concerns products with variants, what should happen with simple products? **2)** Do you intend to replace the entire contents of the tab, add a extra table or add an extra row to the already existing table? **3)** For those who do not use the plugin, where and how is the meta-key stored from GTIN?

Comment: @7uc1f3r 1) simple product should be unaffected 2) add an extra row to the already existing table or possibly replace the "attributes" row 3) The GTIN code is a private custom field of product with meta_key _wpm_gtin_code, If you have the product object you can get the GTIN code in this way: `$gtin = $product->get_meta('_wpm_gtin_code');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following, it will add extra row. Explanation via comment tags added in the code.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    // Variable product
    if ( $product->is_type('variable' ) ) {
        // Get childIDs in an array
        $children_ids = $product->get_children();
        
        // Output
        $output = '';

        // Loop
        foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
            // Get product
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
            
            // Get variation name
            $variation_name = ( $name = implode( ' / ', $variation->get_variation_attributes() ) ) ? $name : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

            // Get product SKU
            $get_sku = ( $sku = $variation->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
            
            // Get GTIN code
            $gtin_value = ( $gtin = $variation->get_meta( '_wpm_gtin_code' ) ) ? $gtin : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
            
            // Concatenate string
            $output .= '<p>' . $variation_name . ' - EAN: ' . $get_sku . ' GTIN: ' . $gtin_value . '</p>';
        }
        
        // Add
        $product_attributes[ 'custom_field' ] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Custom field', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => $output,
        );
    }
    
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'filter_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

---

Result: (GTIN not available because I don't use that plugin)

[image]

---

Related:

- [WooCommerce: Get custom field from product variations and display it on the “additional information area”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853598/woocommerce-get-custom-field-from-product-variations-and-display-it-on-the-add)
- [Display SKU on the 'additional information area' for single and variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169136/display-sku-on-the-additional-information-area-for-single-and-variable-product)

---

**Additional question**

To remove a table row you can simply use:

```php
unset ( $product_attributes['weight'] );
```

But it can also be the other way around where we will indicate via this piece of code which table rows we want to keep

```php
// For debugging purposes - uncomment if needed
//echo '<pre>', print_r( $product_attributes, 1 ), '</pre>';

// Add the rows you want to keep, you can add multiple rows, separated by a comma
$rows_to_keep = array ( 'weight', 'dimensions' );

// Loop 
foreach ( $product_attributes as $key => $product_attribute ) {
    // Not in array 'rows to keep'
    if ( ! in_array ( $key, $rows_to_keep ) ) {
        // Remove
        unset ( $product_attributes[$key] );
    }
}
```

Both pieces of code can be applied in my above answer